# jinja2: Can I render template tags from an expression?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

How would I return text with template markup from an expression and have the tags rendered by Jinja? It looks like Jinja only makes one pass, and just escapes and dumps the text in without further processing it as part of the template (which would be the right thing 99% of the time). Is there a way to make two passes with the renderer, or render the result of my expression first and pass it to the template?

### Simplified Problem

I have included further details below in case there is more to this than I think, but this should be all the information needed for the problem.

If `do_render()` returns `<p>Hello there {{ current_user.name }}</p>`, how could I do the following in a template, so that I obtain the value of `name`?

```
<div>
{{ do_render() }}
</div>
```

This renders as `<div><p>Hello there {{ current_user.name }}</p></div>`, when I want `<div><p>Hello there Sam</p></div>`.

### Complete Problem

I'm using Flask, Flask-Bootstrap, and Flask-Nav with Python 2.7. I could just create the navigation bar myself and none of this would matter, but "autogenerated" sounded so much simpler...

Flask-Bootstrap provides a Flask-Nav compatible renderer; I have subclassed it to modify my navigation bar. I'm trying to add a logon form in the navigation bar, right-aligned. Because the BootstrapRenderer generates the complete navbar, I have to inject my form into it prior to the closing tags (alternatively, I could skip `super()` and do it all myself).

```
class MyRenderer(BootstrapRenderer):
    def visit_Navbar(self, node):
        """ Returns the html for a Bootstrap navigation bar. """
        root = super(MyRenderer, self).visit_Navbar(node)

        # Replace the navbar style with my custom css
        root['class'] = 'navbar navbar-mystyle'

        # Here I try injecting a login form. This is the correct position,
        # and it inserts properly; it just treats {{, }}, {%, %}
        # as nothing special.
        elem = root[0][1] # div class="navbar navbar-collapse"
        elem.add(
            dominate.util.include(
            os.path.join(
            config.app_path_root, app.template_folder, 'inc/login_form.jinja')))

        # I have also tried
        # elem.add('{% block nav_right %}{% endblock %}')
        # thinking I would use inheritance later (still my preference).

        return root
```

I then register the renderer with Flask-Nav, and render it by inserting `{{ nav.main_nav.render() }}` into my base template, which my .html files inherit from. All of this works.

My problem is that I only want the login form when the person is not logged in.

The login_form is:

```
{% if not current_user.is_authenticated() %}
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search" action="login" method="post">
<div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="username" /></div>
<div class="form-group"><input type="password" name="password" /></div>
</form>
{% else %}
<div class="navbar-right">
Welcome {{ current_user.name }} | <a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</a>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

My HTML output is identical to the template; neither statements, expressions, nor comments are treated as such.

Other attempts: I have generated the navbar first, then passed it to the template via `render_template('index.html', navbar=navbar)` but I have the same problem. I have also tried macros. I'm about ready to write my navigation menu in the base template myself and be done with it, but now it feels like that would be giving up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than `{% include ... %}` and `{% extends ... %}`, you're not going to be able to have the template system automatically render something that's added to a template during runtime without a bit of customization.

The beautiful part about Jinja 2 is that its API is very powerful and you can do many things without having to feel like your "hacking" the system. To do what your first example is implying, you just need to have the function render the included template snippet snd return a rendered string. If you're expecting the template to be rendered with the context of the parent template, that's not gonna happen automatically, but that's not a problem since you can pass in whatever you need directly in your function call in the template.

Comment: So much simpler than I was making it. Thank you.